# If a functional sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly then the mean of $f_n$ converges to $f$ proof help

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show the following:

Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be a real-valued function defined on $E$. Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of bounded functions on $E$ which converges to $f$ uniformly on $E$. Prove that

$\frac{f_1(x)+\ldots+f_n(x)}{n} \rightarrow f(x)$

uniformly on $E$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Currently I have the following:

We know that $f_n(x)$ is bounded and converges uniformly to $f(x)$. This means that $f(x)$ is also bounded on E. We can say $|f_n(x)| \leq L$ and $|f(x)| \leq M$, for all $n$, where $L$ is the greatest supremum of all $f_n(x)$ and $M$ is the supremum of $f(x)$.

As it is uniform convergence, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n(x) - f(x)|<\epsilon$.

We try to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon$.

After picking $n$ sufficiently large I try to manipulate $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) - f(x)|$ to dominate it by something which tends towards zero, therefore showing uniform convergence.

$|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) - f(x)| = \frac{1}{n}|\sum_{i=1}^n(f_i(x)-f(x))| \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|f_i(x)-f(x)|$
$\leq \frac{1}{n}|f_1(n)+\ldots+f_{n-1}(x)|+\frac{1}{n}|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \frac{n-1}{n}L +\frac{1}{n}\epsilon$.

My trouble is that in the final line, the limit as n tends towards infinity is $L$, not zero. I am not sure what I have done wrong and would like help finishing the proof. Also this seems like the kind of queston that would already have been posted, but I couldn't find it with a quick search, so sorry if this is a duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost at the end ;-)

From here: $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) - f(x)| = \frac{1}{n}|\sum_{i=1}^n(f_i(x)-f(x))| \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|f_i(x)-f(x)|$

you can use the fact that $\exists N,\forall n>N, |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq\varepsilon$. Let's call $N$ that integer.

Then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|f_i(x)-f(x)| = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N|f_i(x)-f(x)| + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=N+1}^n|f_i(x)-f(x)|$

$ \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N|f_i(x)-f(x)| + \frac{(n-N-1)\varepsilon}{n}$

$\leq \frac1n N(L+M)+ \frac{(n-N-1)\varepsilon}{n}$ (note that it does not depend on $x$ anymore)

For a sufficient large $n$, the first term is close to 0, and the second less than $\varepsilon$.